# How to serialize and deserialize a Hashtable?

Tags: java, serialization, hashtable

I am trying to `Serialize` and `Deserialize` a `Hashtable` but without success.

Here's the code:

**Deserialize**

```
    public static void read(File f) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        FileInputStream fos = new FileInputStream(f);
        ObjectInputStream oos = new ObjectInputStream(fos);

        list = new Hashtable<Date,String>((Hashtable<Date,String>)oos.readObject());
        oos.close();
    }
```

**Serialize**

```
    public static void write(String s) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(s);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(list);
    }
```

I wrote the `Class` Date, it's not Java's, but i did `implemet Serializable` there.

After I `Deserialize` the `Hashtable` and print it I am getting just `{}`.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

**Main Class:**

```
public class Main implements Serializable
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        String[] options = {"Existing file","New file"};

        int choice = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                "Whould you like to use an existing file or make a new file?",
                "Reminders", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, null);

        System.out.println(choice);

        if(choice == 0)  //existing file
        {
            JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex)
            {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }

            int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(null);

            GUI.read(fc.getSelectedFile());
        }
        else if(choice == 1) //new file
        {
            String name;
            do { name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the name of the new file: "); }
            while((name == null) || (name.length() == 0));

            GUI.write(name);
        }
        else if(choice == -1)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Good Bye!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
```

**GUI Class:**

```
public class GUI extends JPanel implements Serializable
{
    private DateGUI date;
    private JButton save;
    private static JTextArea text;
    private JScrollPane scroll;

    private static Hashtable<Date,String> list = new Hashtable<Date,String>;

    public static void read(File f) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        FileInputStream fos = new FileInputStream(f);
        ObjectInputStream oos = new ObjectInputStream(fos);

        list = ((Hashtable<Date,String>)oos.readObject());
        oos.close();
    }

    public static void write(String s) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(s);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

        oos.writeObject(list);
    }
    private class SaveListener implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            if(e.getSource() == save)
            {
                list.put(new Date(DateGUI.getDay(),DateGUI.getMonth(),DateGUI.getYear()), text.getText());
                text.setText("");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**Date Class:** has 3 `String` fields of day,month,year. I did impelement Serializable and override `equals` and `HashCode`.

**DateGUI Class:** has `GUI` "stuff" and:

```
    public static String getDay()
    {
        return (String)day.getSelectedItem();
    }

    public static String getMonth()
    {
        return (String)month.getSelectedItem();
    }

    public static String getYear()
    {
        return (String)year.getSelectedItem();
    }

   private class ShowListener implements ActionListener
   {
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
       {
           if(e.getSource() == show)
           {
               GUI.set(GUI.get(getDay(), getMonth(), getYear()));
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: `Hashtable` has been deprecated for a long time. Use a `Map`.

Comment: @LutzHorn This is for homework. I have to use ```Hashtable``` :/

Comment: Please show us the exception stacktrace.

Comment: @StephenC Where do i get it? I am using Eclipse

Comment: Did you implement `hashCode` and `equals` in `Date`?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes i did

Comment: do not forget to close the streams (your ``write`` method is wrong).

Comment: Actually if you are getting some output, maybe there isn't one.

Comment: I think there is something important you are not showing us.  Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: @StephenC My ```Main``` ```Class``` let the user choose either make new file or read from existing file. If the user chooses to make a new file so ```write``` method i called from ```Main``` with the ```String``` which is the name of the file that the user have choose. But i think it doesn't Serialize the ```Hashtable``` correctly. I did implement this with ```Java's``` ```GUI``` so everytime the user clicks a ```Save``` button in the GUI, the program stores the reminder in the ```Hashtable```. Do i need to add there the method ```write``` so it'll be called on every new reminder added?

Comment: I think your assumption that serializing `Hashtable` doesn't work is incorrect.  It is a class that has been used by millions of other people.  If there were bugs in it they would have been found ... 20 years ago.  The real problem is probably some bug in some part of your code that you are not showing us.  We need an MCVE.

Comment: And to answer your question ... not necessarily, and that may or not be related to your actual problem; i.e. whatever is (apparently) causing the hashtable to load as empty.

Comment: @StephenC I am working on it right now. I'll edit my question when done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After I deserialize the `Hashtable` and print it I am getting just `{}`.
>
> What am I doing wrong?

This code is copied from your MCVE code.  You have since edited it out, but I am convinced that this or something like it was the real cause of your problem.

```
public static void write(String s) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    list = new Hashtable<Date,String>();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(s);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

    oos.writeObject(list);
}
```

You should call `close()` on `oos`, but that's not the real problem.

(The missing `close()` *may* cause the serialized file to be empty or incomplete / corrupt, but that would NOT lead to you reading back an empty `Hashtable`.  You wold get an exception instead.  Note that the `new FileOutputStream(s)` will truncate the file ...)

The real problem is the first statement of the method.  You are *unconditionally* assigning a new empty `Hashtable` to `list`.  Then you are writing it.  So (naturally) when you read back what you wrote to the file you will get an empty `Hashtable` again.  That's what the `{}` you were seeing means.

In short, your code is writing out an empty table and reading it back again. `Hashtable` serialization is working as it is supposed to work.

Comment: Sorry, all the changes i did and i forgot to redo it. This line wasn't there. I did edit it again. The Hashtable creation is now where its declared. ```private static Hashtable<Date,String> list = new Hashtable<Date,String>;```

Comment: OK.  Now add the missing `close()`.  When you run the code does it work now?

Comment: I added "manually" a reminder (```list.put(new Date("1","1","2020"), "Hello");```) in ```write``` method and it did add it to the ```Hashtable```. But when i use the ```GUI``` and i add reminders then i ```Serialize``` and ```Deserialize``` the ```Hashtable``` and I am getting only the reminder i added "manually". Do i need to call write method just before terminating the program so this way it'll store all reminders in the ```Hashtable``` and if so, where is it possible to put it in the code? The ```GUI``` "takes control" so I can't put it somewhere in the code to be executed sequentially

Comment: You need to hook it into the action listener for the close event for the application's main window.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should flush after writing.

> oos.writeObject(list);
>   oos.close();

Comment: Yes, it will flush implicitly when close. Point is here, he didn't flush or close in original program.

Comment: So fix your answer then!   Because that is NOT the point that you are making in your answer.  *"I believe you should flush after writing."*

Comment: And besides, if the problem was that the data was not written to the file, then when you attempted to read it you would get an exception not an empty `Hashtable` like he says.

Answer (score 0):

Are you even writing anything to the file, because the write method is taking in a String as a parameter, but you haven't specified which file you are writing to. Try:

```
public static void write(File f) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

    Hashtable<Date, String> list = new Hashtable<>();
    list.put(YourDateObject, "String");

    oos.writeObject(list);
}
```

Comment: The string is the name of the file that the user provides in the ```Main``` ```Class```

Comment: have you checked whether the file contains the serialised data after you have wrote to it?

Comment: Yes, it stores there the serialized data

Answer (score 0):

Here is code example:

```
public class Main {

/**
 * File name
 */
private final static String FILENAME = "test.bin";

/**
 * Entry point
 * 
 * @param args
 * @throws Exception 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Hashtable<Date, String> original = new Hashtable<>();

    // write some data to hashtable
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i ++) {
        original.put(new Date(), String.valueOf(i));
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);
    }

    // serialize
    write(FILENAME, original);

    // deserialize
    Hashtable<Date, String> restored = read(FILENAME);

    // compare results
    System.out.println(restored);
    System.out.println(restored);
}

/**
 * Deserialization
 * 
 * @param filename
 * @return
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws ClassNotFoundException 
 */
public static Hashtable<Date, String> read(String filename) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    try (ObjectInputStream oos = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename))) {
        return (Hashtable<Date, String>) oos.readObject();
    }
}

/**
 * Serialization
 * 
 * @param filename
 * @param list
 * @throws FileNotFoundException
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public static void write(String filename, Hashtable<Date, String> list) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    try(ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename))) {
        oos.writeObject(list);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I am using ```Java's``` ```GUI``` so everytime the user stores a reminder in the ```Hashtable``` he clicks a ```Save``` button. How should i implement this? Put write method after every click on the Save button?